# model.getProperty returns undefined

Tags: javascript, sapui5

When I am writing the below code in my `onInit` function, I am getting this error:

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

But when I am writing the code inside my button press event, then its working fine.

```js
var i;
var oMod = sap.ui.getCore().getModel();
var itab = oMod.getProperty("/empTab");
for (i = 0; i < itab.length; i++) {
  if (itab[i].empName === 'Sohail') {
    itab[i].Smoker = false;
    oMod.setProperty("/empTab", itab);
  } else {
    itab[i].Smoker = true;
    oMod.setProperty("/empTab", itab);
  }
}
```

Comment: What kind of model does `sap.ui.getCore().getModel();` return? Is it an ODataModel? Or JSONModel? And when is the `/empTab` filled? How does the structure of your model data look like? The question is lacking in important details..

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have the exact same issue as below

[Component + default OData model: this.getView().getModel() returns undefined in onInit() of controllers](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/790)

Use

```
this.getOwnerComponent().getModel()
```

Inside your onInit function as the global model is still not recognized during this lifecycle stage of your view.

Comment: It's an old question but I think accessing the model was not the problem. Otherwise the browser would've complained that it _Cannot read property `getProperty` of undefined_.